# Is talcum powder really beneficial for a tyre tube?

Tags: tires

The local mechanic who replaced my motorcycle tyre tube added what looked like talcum powder to the insides of the tyre before inserting the new tube. I asked him the advantage of doing that and he didn't know for sure. He just said it helps the tube move freely in the tyre. Sounded like nonsense to me, so I Googled it.

There were three opinions I came across:
1. [Talcum powder does not help at all](http://sheldonbrown.com/brandt/talcum.html)
2. [It helps reduce friction between tyre and tube](http://www.bikeforums.net/archive/index.php/t-272672.html)
3. [It prevents the tube from vulcanizing and sticking to the tyre when it gets too hot](http://draco.nac.uci.edu/rbfaq/FAQ/8b.11.html)

Are any of these reasons credible? Which is the real reason for using talcum powder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards your option no 2, it can often be awkward getting the tube to sit evenly in the tyre. Powder allows it to move without sticking, making it easier to fit the tyre.

Comment: It's just for getting it in place and letting it move around as needed easier.  Could help avoid a tear or pinch failure too.  It's standard procedure on motorcycle and airplane tire tube installations.

Answer (score 1):

hope it can help solve some doubts.
I don't know exactly what talcum powder does, but I own two scuba masks and a snorkel tube, all of them with rubbert parts. I had managed buying new googles when I was younger because of the rubber parts fading away, cracked rubber. An old fisherman told me to powder googles, snorkel and fins with rubber into a bag or box. I did it, and since then I haven't bought again googles neither fins, but the snorkel that I forgot powdering with talcum...

Fins and googles where bought 1997. Don't know in which way it acts, but we are in 2017, and they are perfect.  Hope it may give a light.

Answer (score -3):

One of the main reasons is, that when accelerating or braking, the tire, being in contact with the road, can rotate more quickly or slowly; however, the tube is connected to the wheel rim via the inflation valve, which ergo must rotate at the same rate as the metal rim, without the valve becoming pressed sideways, and exerting an unwanted torque on the tube, which may lead to a puncture. The talc reduces the tire/tube friction, and allows the tire to rotate slightly faster or slower, without any ill effects on the tube. The other reasons mentioned are of course also beneficial. Jock

Comment: Tyres cannot rotate at a different speed to the rim, if they could brakes would become utterly useless...

Comment: That's all utter bull, tyres might only rotate relatively to the rim if you're driving a top fuel dragster or something alike.

Comment: A tyre will break friction with the road surface long before the tyre beading breaks traction with the wheel rim.